# SQL Distinct with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem in options If I embed `DISTINCT` in query I have `value= ""`. If I remove `DISTINCT` I have `value= "1"` and I need this.

```
 $query_result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT C.name FROM Category AS C INNER JOIN MarketProduct AS MP ON C.Category_ID = MP.ID_Category WHERE MP.ID_Market ='$id'");

<select name="ID_Category">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_result)){   
?>

<option value="<?php echo $row['ID_Category'] ; ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ; ?></option>


<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `DISTINCT`, use `GROUP BY`. See below:

```
  $query_result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT C.name FROM Category AS C INNER JOIN MarketProduct AS MP ON C.Category_ID = MP.ID_Category WHERE MP.ID_Market ='$id' GROUP BY C.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the DISTINCT operator. You are only selecting one field in your query which is name. You need to select also the ID_Category field. Somehting like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.name, C.Category_ID FROM Category AS C INNER JOIN MarketProduct AS MP ON C.Category_ID = MP.ID_Category WHERE MP.ID_Market ='$id'
```